# Keep aspect ratio of Linear Layout background images Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have four images which are squares and I am displaying them as background images in nested Linear layouts. The images are stretched height-wise and I am not sure if it is possible to somehow keep the aspect ratio of these images when displaying them as backgrounds in Linear Layouts.

The Linear Layouts dimensions are defined by using weights, I tried messing around with the Android scale parameter but none of the examples I found seemed to work with Linear Layouts.

Is it possible to ensure the height remains the same size as the width?

here is the main part of my XML code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/columnLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/engtoitaButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/engtoita"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/playPhraseButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/play"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/columnRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itatoengButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/itatoeng"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/openPhrasesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/book"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use image views nested in your linear layout and set the src to the drawable, pretty sure that handles scaling while maintaining aspect ratio.